# Can someone port this to C?

Tags: php, c

I've spent the last few hours trying to port this to C, with no success. Can someone please help?

```
function zerofill($a, $b) {
    $z = hexdec(80000000);
    if ($z & $a) {
        $a = ($a>>1);
        $a &= (~$z);
        $a |= 0x40000000;
        $a = ($a>>($b-1));
    } else {
        $a = ($a>>$b);
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: Post your C equivalent.

Comment: Please post your current C code and tell us which problems you exactly have.

Comment: "I've spent the last few hours trying to port this to C, with no success." - you forgot to also say that you had spent days searching the internet for  a solution.

Comment: @Paul - wild guess mind you, but it looks like it's going to shift $a to the right by $b bits, filling the vacated spaces with the value of the original high-order bit. Of course, we'd like to hear from the OP on this matter...

Comment: @Paul - it is something to do with "Google Pagerank in PHP" (it's on the OP's web site).

Comment: @Bob: so a rotate? O.o... strange. I don't see how that is `zerofill`. I would like OP to mention what exactly his code /should/ do (and what it's not doing).

Comment: @Paul - kinda sorta I'm thinking. Whatever the intent, I don't think it's intended to fill with zeroes. Then again, a response from OP, a comment, or identifiers longer than one character would be welcome!

Comment: Mike Chess, yes, you guessed it right. I'm making a c version of it.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
unsigned int zerofill(unsigned int a, int b) {
    return a >> b;
}
```

Or,

```
int zerofill(int a, int b) {
    return ((unsigned int)a) >> b;
}
```

In C, the right shift operator acts as an arithmetic shift if its left operand is signed, or a logical shift if unsigned. It appears that the original PHP code is going to some lengths to get an unsigned shift using only a signed shift.

The C99 standard at section 6.5.7 says:

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. 
>   If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a 
>   nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
>   part of the quotient of `E1 / 2^E2`. If `E1` has a signed type 
>   and a negative value, the resulting value is 
>   implementation-defined.

This says clearly that to get zero bits shifted in, the operand must be either unsigned, or signed and positive. The only question is the behavior when the operand is signed and negative where the result is implementation defined. In practice, every implementation I've encountered has treated that case by sign extension so that the result still makes sense as a division by a power of two when integer values are stored as two's complement.

I don't have the reference at hand, but C89 said effectively the same thing, and established practice before the C standard was also consistent with this interpretation.

Comment: Although this works with all numbers, this doesn't work with all numbers. I've tried a similar method in PHP before, and it didn't work well. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: This answer is right.  It's not *possible* to "try a similar method in PHP", since PHP doesn't have an `unsigned int` type.

Comment: Not knowing PHP I wasn't willing to make the bald assertion, but none of the fuss would be required if PHP did have an `unsigned` integer type and logical shift right.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but then, most of the code is the same.

```
int zerofill(int a, int b) {
    int z = 0x80000000;
    if (z & a) {
        a = a >> 1;
        a &= ~z;
        a |= 0x40000000;
        a = a >> (b - 1);
    } else {
        a = a >> b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Can someone now port this to Assembler?

Comment: Lua please.

Also, I believe that C provides >>=, |=, etc operators.

Comment: LISP, please.  I need to test this in XEmacs.

Comment: @Felix: Probably because it's just giving the exact answer to the OP instead of helping him figure out the actual problems he had?

Comment: Thanks Samir Talwar. It works perfectly. DeadMG, >>= does not return the same results.

Comment: @jamessan: That's fair enough. I figured seeing a working code sample would be beneficial too. Perhaps seeing the similarities between PHP and C in this case will help the OP. Perhaps it won't. Can't be sure until we try.

Comment: Definitely gonna need this in INTERCAL next.

Comment: Watch for the signed/unsigned difference. The 4th line, specifically, will be sensitive to that.